# How to run python script using S3 data in AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, job-scheduling

I have a CSV file in S3. I want to run a python script using data present in S3. The S3 file will change once in a week. I need to pass an input argument to my python script which loads my S3 file into Pandas and do some calculation to return the result.

Currently I am loading this S3 file using Boto3 in my server for each input argument. This process takes more time to return the result, and my nginx returns with 504 Gateway timeout.

I am expecting some AWS service to do it in cloud. Can anyone point me in a right direction which AWS service is suitable to use here

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Use AWS Lambda, but Lambda has limited local storage (500mb) and memory (3gb) with 15 run time.
2. Since you mentioned Pandas I recommend using AWS Glue which has ability:

   - Detect new file
   - Large Mem, CPU supported
   - Visual data flow
   - Support Spark DF
   - Ability to query data from your CSV files
   - Connect to different database engines.

We currently use AWS Glue for our data parser processes